# To "favor someone's side of the house"

Tags: literature, figurative-language

I just read the sci-fi short story ["And all the earth a grave"](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/23146/23146-h/23146-h.htm), and I don't get the punch line.

To summarize the story: A company starts an aggressive marketing effort on selling coffins, which results in (almost) all of the world's population buying coffins and happily going extinct.

In the end, a lone man and his donkey find an abandoned city and have the following exchange:

> A half-buried piece of newspaper fluttered in the breeze. He walked forward slowly and picked it up. It told him enough so that he understood.
>
> "They're gone, Evie," he said to the burro, "all gone." He put his arm affectionately around her neck. "I reckon it's up to me and you agin [sic]. We got to start all over." He stood back and gazed at her with mild reproach. "I shore [sic] hope they don't favor your side of the house so much this time."

What does the expression *"favor your side of the house"* mean in this context?

Comment: It's really a matter of interpretation. The story has the rather bizarre premise that if big business starts vastly overproducing coffins, this will somehow encourage people to not only *buy* all these coffins, but actually start *using* them (by deliberately ending their own lives). In that light, it seems likely *your side of the house* means the *donkey-like, asinine, dumb* side (of "the mammal kingdom", for example). But honestly, it's a pretty low-quality text, and the expression seems somewhat "unusual". Also, *your side of the **family*** would be a more likely metaphoric usage here.

Comment: The way I read it, the man is saying that animals came off better in the end, but not necessarily that the "donkey-like, asinine, dumb side" came off better, because the humans ended up being the stupid ones.

Comment: @stangdon: Like I say, it's a matter of interpretation. I only briefly skimmed the link, so I don't really know how much difference it would make if I'd read properly. But *logically* it seems perfectly credible to me that the implication is "they" (leaders of big business? the aliens who *really* control humanity? evolutionary imperatives?) pandered to dumb people as opposed to sensible people, rather than humanity as opposed to dumb animals. I partly assume that because the plot device looks ridiculously dumb (since I've *bought* a coffin, I'd better kill myself now to make good use of it!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, "favor your side of the house" means "look or act like your side of the family".  As FumbleFingers points out in his comment, "favor your side of the family" is the more common way to express this.  For example, a dark-haired man with a blonde wife and a blonde daughter might say that the daughter "favors your side of the family" because of her light coloration.

This can also be used in a derogatory way, for example someone in an unhappy relationship might point to their lazy, vapid offspring and say, "They definitely favor **your** side of the family," to insinuate that their spouse's family are also lazy and vapid.

In English, the donkey is often used as a metaphor for extreme and unproductive stubbornness (because of the animal's infamous nature).  "Muleheaded" is a synonym for "stubborn".  In this story, my interpretation is that the man hopes future generations of humans aren't so stupid and intractable that they kill themselves off again.

As a side note:  I didn't read the story but my guess is that "coffins" are used as a metaphor for things like global warming where we collectively and eagerly are ["digging our own graves"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dig-your-own-grave).  But more than this, what most bothers me is the suggestion that a man can repopulate the human race with a burro.  It's an awkward way to punctuate the end of the story.

[Edit] The story was originally written in the 1963 when science fiction authors were getting into this kind of dystopian future, probably more in response to nuclear weapons than any environmental factors.  It is, of course, satire. and so the ending isn't as awkward since it's not meant to be taken *literally*.

Comment: I always forget the difference between asses, donkeys, burros, and mules, so I just had to google it again. Apparently it's ***mules*** that are the sterile hybrid, so our intrepid hero might have a bit more chance of repopulating the planet with his burro. I was gonna say *hopefully **female** burro* there, but that's a mental image too far for me. I'd rather assume he's being a bit more metaphoric, and that "the burro's side of the family" means "people who are as dumb as donkeys", rather than *actual* donkeys. But that's a minor point - it's an excellent summary of relevant associations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I finally read through the fairly short story and it's clearly satire, so I don't think you're suppose to assume any kind of literal interspecies "repopulation".